# How to assign already created endpoint in Amazon sagemaker notebook

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, amazon-sagemaker

I have created a sagemaker endpoint using my preferred modeled.
with this code

```
predictor=estimator.deploy(initial_instance_count=1, instance_type='ml.m4.xlarge')
```

so whenever I want to predict a data, I can only use `predictor.predict(data)` and everything went fine.

But now I am out of notebook session for a while and need to restart the instance and kernal. So my above code doesn't work anymore as the variables get reset.

I try searching for **how to assign sagemaker endpoint to a variable** but everything leads to invoke endpoint with body data.

All I want is I want to use like `predictor = "endpoint-name'` and then `predictor.predict(data)` works fine. Any way to get this.
*sorry for my english.*

Answer (score 1):

How about [this](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/inference/predictors.html)?

```
from sagemaker.predictor import Predictor

predictor = Predictor(endpoint_name="your endpoint name")
```